# QGIS Plugin: display dialog for entering username and password to connect to the database

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, postgresql, qgis-plugins

I do not want the password and username to be saved in the QGIS project.

Instead of standard QGis dialog(QgsCredentialDialog) I want to display "my dialog" for entering username and password.
On the "button connect" :connect to DB(Postgresql) (just like standard dialog of qgis is doing but I want to do it with my dialog)

The idea is to connect the signal that is emitted when the project starts  to load into QGIS...

Anyone have solution for this?

Comment: Just for clarity, your requirement is "that password and username is not stored in the project" or that "you need to show your own dialog"? The first one is possible without the second one.